# Node.js CLI hashbang under CoffeeScript?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, command-line-interface

How would I preserve the top-of-file hashbang when converting a Node.js CLI to CoffeeScript?

```
#! /usr/bin/env node <-- What to do with this?

try
  require('./cli/main') process.argv 
catch
  require('./cli/error').err _error, true
```

Clarification: I'm looking to emit JavaScript that preserves the hashbang as is, not change the hashbang to use Coffee, if that makes sense.

Comment: The suggested way is to add it after the compilation: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/pull/3330

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @ShanShan Your comment answers the question and provides a link to a canonical source. If you'll rephrase as a question I can accept.